# How does javascript implement assign operations to window.location object

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie to js and recently I've learned that we can navigate to a new page in a browser tab by assigning a new value to the `window.location` object like: `window.location = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"`. But I'm confused about this assign operation. In javascript, a variable changes it's type and value in an assign operation. For example, when running the following program segment, the type of `a` will be **undefined** then **number** and finally **string**:

```
var a;
a = 1;
a = "str";
```

But assigning a string object (i.e. the url) to `window.location` doesn't change it's type, `window.location` is still an instance of `Location` class, only with some of it's attributes changed (e.g. `window.location.href`, `window.location.host` etc.). This is just like overloading the "**=**" operator with the `window.location.assign()` function, but it seems that javascript doesn't offer an overload mechanism. I have no idea what do browsers (i.e. the javascript running environment) do to achieve this. I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: soooo what is problem

Comment: It is just a `setter` probably: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov The problem is when you assign a string object (an url) to `window.location` , it doesn't become the string object but  use the the url to change it's attributes instead, just as `window.location.assign()` is called.

Comment: You didn't choose the most simple object to feed your curiosity ;-) Have a look at [that note](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#the-location-interface) from the specifcations themselves (yes the normally technical texts that implementers like browsers should follow). Location is actually not a proper JS object, it's a DOM object which gets wrapped into a JS object later. But that's probably more confusing than anything else, so let's pretend it's just a getter like others since you seem interested only by that part of the monster.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your help! I spent some time reading the WHATWG standard and then the W3C IDL document, and finally found the answer. The behavior of assigning a url to window.location is defined in [the IDL of the window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#the-window-object), where the assign operation to window.location is [forwarded](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#PutForwards) to window.location.href. Thank you for offering a clue so that I can find the rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a setter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set in combination with `location.assign()` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign ) being called behind the scenes.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location :
"Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document will be loaded using the URL as if location.assign()".